# MemoryError while performing k-medoids clustering with scikit-learn on small dataset

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to apply a k-medoids clustering using `scikit-learn`, but there is a memory error although the dataset size is 26 MB.

error:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.33 TiB for an array with shape (426740, 426740) and data type float64
```

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('dish.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 5:].values
print(X)

# Taking care of missing data
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
imputer.fit(X[:, 2:])
X[:, 2:] = imputer.transform(X[:, 2:])
print(X)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X[:, :2] = sc.fit_transform(X[:, :2])
print(X)


from sklearn_extra.cluster import KMedoids

n_clusters = 25

kmedoids = KMedoids(n_clusters=n_clusters, random_state=1).fit(X[:, :])

cluster_labels = kmedoids.labels_

print(cluster_labels)

cluster_centers = kmedoids.cluster_centers_

dataset['Cluster'] = cluster_labels
dataset.to_csv("clustered_dish.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same issue but with a dataset size of about ~1.1 million. The memory error I received was telling me that I needed about 10 terabytes of memory to be able to run K-Medoids over my dataset, which is absolutely insane. I did some research and I can provide you with some more information regarding this issue.

## K-Medoids vs K-Means

### K-Medoids

- In the KMedoids algorithm, a distance matrix is computed to store the pairwise distances between each data point and every other data point in the dataset.
- If you have N data points, this results in an `N x N` matrix. The matrix contains the distance values for all possible pairs of data points.
- The distance matrix is required for the algorithm to determine the most representative points (medoids) within each cluster.

Essentially, this distance matrix is needed since the medoid is defined as the data point that minimizes the sum of distances from itself to all other data points in the dataset. Thus, we need the distances between all pairs of points to make a decision about the medoid.

### K-Means

- In the KMeans algorithm, instead of storing a distance matrix, only the coordinates of the cluster centroids are kept.
- For each cluster, only a vector representing the centroid is stored. The centroid is the mean (average) of all data points within that cluster.
- The memory usage for KMeans is proportional to the number of clusters (`K`) because you store the centroid coordinates for each cluster.

## K-Medoids vs K-Means Example

Let's break down the above points with a simple example.

### K-Medoids

Let's consider a small dataset with three data points (`N = 3`). In K-Medoids, we compute the pairwise distances and create a distance matrix.

Suppose we have the following data points in a 2-D space:

```
A (1, 2)
B (3, 5)
C (6, 1)
```

**Step 1:** First, let's calculate the pair-wise distances between these points using Euclidean distance:

```
Distance(A, B) = sqrt((3-1)^2 + (5-2)^2) = sqrt(5)
Distance(A, C) = sqrt((6-1)^2 + (1-2)^2) = sqrt(26)
Distance(B, C) = sqrt((6-3)^2 + (1-5)^2) = sqrt(18)
```

**Step 2:** Now, let's create our distance matrix. We will get a matrix that looks like this:

```
   | A         | B         | C
--------------------------------
A | 0         | sqrt(5)    | sqrt(26)
B | sqrt(5)    | 0         | sqrt(18)
C | sqrt(26)   | sqrt(18)   | 0
```

This is a symmetric matrix where the diagonal elements are always 0 (distance from a point to itself).

In larger datasets with more points, this matrix becomes larger and denser, containing all pairwise distances. The memory requirements for storing this matrix increase with the square of the number of data points (`N`).

### K-Means

Let's consider a small dataset with three data points (`N = 3`).

Suppose we have the following data points in a 2-D space:

```
A (1, 2)
B (3, 5)
C (6, 1)
```

Now, let's say we want to perform KMeans clustering with `K = 2`. The algorithm will find two centroids, one for each cluster.

**Step 1:** Let's assume the initial centroids are assigned randomly, and we'll update them iteratively.

```
Centroid 1: (2, 3)
Centroid 2: (4, 4)
```

**Step 2:** Based on the proximity to centroids, each data point is assigned to the nearest cluster.

```
Cluster 1: [A]
Cluster 2: [B, C]
```

**Step 3:** The centroids are updated as the mean of the data points in each cluster.

```
Updated Centroid 1: (1, 2)
Updated Centroid 2: (4.5, 3)
```

Steps 2 and 3 are repeated until convergence.

In K-Means, only the coordinates of the final centroids need to be stored. In this case, we have two centroids (`K = 2`), and each centroid is a vector representing the mean of the data points in its cluster.

The memory usage for K-Means is proportional to the number of clusters (`K`). In this example, we have two centroids, so the memory usage is determined by the storage of these two centroid vectors.

### Example Conclusion

As you can see, storing an `N x N` matrix requires much more memory than storing `K` number of clusters.

## Final Conclusion

K-Medoids clustering is a variant of K-means that is more robust to noises and outliers. Instead of using the mean point as the center of a cluster, K-Medoids uses an actual point in the cluster to represent it.

K-Medoids is much more computationally expensive than K-Means, particularly in terms of memory usage. The main reason is that K-Medoids requires storing a distance matrix for all pairs of data points, whereas K-Means only requires storing the cluster centroids. This means that as the size of the dataset grows, the memory requirements for K-Medoids grows quadratically, while the memory requirements for K-Means grow linearly.

## Suggestions

In this section, let's discuss some practical solutions and some more things you can read to understand and possibly remedy this issue in the future.

### Solving the Problem

- The first thing that you can do is, well, get more memory. However, this is not a practical solution since, in your case, you would need over 1 terabyte of memory and I would need about 10 terabytes.
- The second thing is that you can use a different algorithm. Is there a reason that you are selecting K-Medoids over K-Means? I was using K-Medoids because I had outliers affecting the centroids in K-Means. Outlier removal may be a potential solution, but this really depends on the problem at hand and how your data is structured.
- You can use a different algorithm. For example CLARA or CLARANS. CLARA (Clustering Large Applications, (Kaufman and Rousseeuw 1990)) is an extension to k-medoids (PAM) methods to deal with data containing a large number of objects (more than several thousand observations) in order to reduce computing time and RAM storage problem. This is achieved using the sampling approach. This can be achieved using the `pyclustering` package.

### Further Reading

This seems to be a well-known issue in the academic world and there are some attempts to remedy this issue. If you are interested you can read more about it in these articles:

1. Schubert, E., & Rousseeuw, P. J. (2019). Faster k-medoids clustering: improving the PAM, CLARA, and CLARANS algorithms. In Similarity Search and Applications: 12th International Conference, SISAP 2019, Newark, NJ, USA, October 2–4, 2019, Proceedings 12 (pp. 171-187). Springer International Publishing.
2. Ushakov, A. V., & Vasilyev, I. (2021). Near-optimal large-scale k-medoids clustering. Information Sciences, 545, 344-362.